# Trilateration of a signal using Time Difference of Arrival

Tags: algorithm, math, audio, signal-processing, trilateration

I am having some trouble to find or implement an algorithm to find a signal source. The objective of my work is to find the sound emitter position.

To accomplish this I am using three microfones. The technique that I am using is **multilateration** that is based on the **time difference of arrival**.

The **time difference of arrival** between each microfones are found using **Cross Correlation** of the received signals.

I already implemented the algorithm to find the **time difference of arrival**, but my problem is more on how **multilateration** works, it's unclear for me based on my reference, and I couldn't find any other good reference for this that are free/open.

If you have some references on how I can implement a **multilateration algorithm**, or some other **trilateration algorithm** that I can use based on **time difference of arrival** it would be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the paper [A Novel Trilateration Algorithm for Localization of a Transmitter/Receiver Station in a 2D Plane Using Analytical Geometry](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265336167_A_Novel_Trilateration_Algorithm_for_Localization_of_a_TransmitterReceiver_Station_in_a_2D_Plane_Using_Analytical_Geometry) will help you. It literally marries the two concepts of trilateration and multilateration into one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point you are looking for is the intersection of three hyperbolas. I am assuming 2D here since you only use 3 receptors. Technically, you can find a unique 3D solution but as you likely have noise, I assume that if you wanted a 3D result, you would have taken 4 microphones (or more).

The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilateration) makes some computations for you. They do it in 3D, you just have to set z = 0 and solve for system of equations (7).

The system is overdetermined, so you will want to solve it in the least squares sense (this is the point in using 3 receptors actually).

Comment: Is there any way you can show how to do this in 3D? Big thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I can help you with multi-lateration in general.

Basically, if you want a solution in 3d - you have to have at least 4 points and 4 distances from them (2-give you the circle in which is the solution - because that is the intersection between 2 spheres, 3 points give you 2 possible solutions (intersection between 3 spheres) - so, in order to have one solution - you need 4 spheres). So, when you have some points (4+) and the distance between them (there is an easy way to transform the TDOA into the set of equations for just having the length type distances /not time/) you need a way to solve the set of equations. First - you need a cost function (or solution error function, as I call it) which would be something like

```
err(x,y,z) = sum(i=1..n){sqrt[(x-xi)^2 + (y-yi)^2 + (z-zi)^2] - di}
```

where `x`, `y`, `z` are coordinates of the current point in the numerical solution and `xi`, `yi`, `zi` and `di` are the coordinates and distance towards the ith reference point. In order to solve this - my advice is NOT to use Newton/Gauss or Newton methods. You need first and second derivative of the aforementioned function - and those have a finite discontinuation in some points in space - hence that is not a smooth function and these methods won't work. What will work is direct search family of algorithms for optimization of functions (finding minimums and maximums. in our case - you need minimum of the error/cost function).

That should help anyone wanting to find a solution for similar problem.

Comment: Can you please help me with a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52192584/clear-simple-example-of-how-to-calculate-tdoa-time-difference-of-arrival