# Clear & simple example of how to calculate TDOA (Time Difference Of Arrival)

Tags: javascript, math

Trying to calculate TDOA (Time Difference Of Arrival) but I can’t get my head around it. Can someone please help me with an clear and simple example.

I have 3 microphone located at:

```
X0 = 0 cm
Y0 = 0 cm
-
X1 = 0 cm
Y1 = 15 cm
-
X2 = 0 cm
Y2 = 30 cm
```

Time different of sound arrive to the 3 microphone:

```
A0 = 0 sec
A1 = 0.002 sec
A2 = 0.004 sec
```

Speed of sound:

```
S = 340 m/sec
```

**Updated after response from wessel**
I am trying to make a script calc TDOA

```
let ? = (Y1 - Y0) / (S);         // = 0.00044
let ? = (Y2 - Y0) / (S);         // = 0.00088
let VX = (X1 - X0) / A0;         // = NaN
let VY = (Y1 - Y0) / A0;         // = Infinity
let V = Math.sqrt(VX^2 + VY^2)   // = 1.4142
let alpha = atan(VY / VX)        // = NaN

console.log(alpha+' deg with the x-axis.');
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I have tried many calc. But I can’t get it to work. So if you know how. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you have a distance and a speed (distance / time), you get a time by doing distance / speed = distance / (distance / time ) = distance / distance * time = time.

What you omit in your question, is the direction and the shape of the sound wave. If the sound is traveling along the x-axis, the shape does not matter, and the time difference would be:

```
(A1 - A0) = (X1 - X0) / (340 m/s) = 0.15 / 340 s = 0.00044 s         
(A2 - A0) = (X2 - X0) / (340 m/s) = 0.3 / 340 s = 0.00088 s
```

If the shape is a straight line, e.g. from an infinitely far point source or from a particularly shaped non-point source, the different of arrival time is given by the x-component of the direction of the sound wave:

```
VX = (X1 - X0) / (A1 - A0) = 37.5 m/s.
```

The total sound speed, which you give as 340 m/s, should equal

```
V = Sqrt(VX^2 + VY^2)
```

such that you can work out that

```
VY = Sqrt(V^2 - VX^2) = 338 m/s
```

or

```
VY = -Sqrt(V^2 - VX^2) = -338 m/s
```

such that your sound wave must in incoming under an angle alpha:

```
alpha = atan(VY / VX) = 83 deg
```

with the x-axis.

I don't see why javascript is relevant here, though. Just in case: use Math.sqrt, Math.pow or V*V, and Math.atan or Math.atan2 (beware of the order of the arguments there!).

Comment: I am trying to calc this in a simple js code. But I still can't get it to work. I update my question with my calc so can you see what is wrong. Best

Comment: I had a typo in VX, which have your NaN. But it's not clear to me what you really need.